# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\TrabalhoDeSI\proceslogin.php on line 22

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

// Busca as variaveis $login e $senha 

$login=$_POST['login']; 
$senha=$_POST['senha']; 

// Conecta ao servidor e selecione a database.
 $conn= new mysqli("localhost","root","","registro");
if($conn->connect_error){
die("Falhou a ligação: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
// Proteção contra  MySQL injection 
//$login = stripslashes($login);
//$senha = stripslashes($senha);
//$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($login);
//$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($senha);

    $result=mysqli_query("SELECT utilizador, senha FROM utilizadores WHERE utilizador='$login' and senha='$senha'");

        $_num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($_num < 1){
            echo " Não esta registado  <br>  faça login <br>";
        }else{
            header;
        }
    exit;
?
```

Comment: Miguel, aproveitando o embalo da sua pergunta, inclusive já foi respondida. Como você está usando mysqli, recomendo você utilizar Prepared Statement e não concatenar as variáveis diretamente no SQL. Recomendo a leitura: http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/ ou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629328/how-to-use-mysqli-prepared-statements-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Você deve mudar a seguinte linha:

> $result=mysqli_query("SELECT utilizador, senha FROM utilizadores WHERE utilizador='$login' and senha='$senha'");

para:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT utilizador, senha FROM utilizadores WHERE utilizador='$login' and senha='$senha'");
```

Repare que antes do `sql` eu adicionei a variável `$conn`. Você deve passar a conexão utilizada e o `sql` para executar.

Você pode ver mais detalhes [Clicando Aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)